# Meaning of "ask for"

Tags: meaning

I always wanted to understand the meaning of the word `for` when coming after `ask`, and I have two question about it:

Let's say that `I'm asking for a flower on behalf of my mother`.

1. If the flower man asks me:`"For whom do you ask me for a flower?"`
   and I answer him `"I ask it for my mother"` - is it equal to :`"For whom do you ask for a flower"` and `"I ask for my mother"` ?
   To be clearer: Do I have to mention any **noun** after I say `ask` so it wouldn't sound as if I want someone to give me my mother?
2. What is the difference between `I'm asking a flower` and `I'm
   asking for a flower`?

   Do the first option have to be that I'm talking to flowers?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Although 'ask' is often used transitively (he asked the teacher / she asked a question / they asked directions / I'd like to ask you [for] a favour / they're asking $200 for it / they ask too much of him / he asked us to dinner), not every sort of direct object is commonly used (*I asked a flower for her / *I asked him a flower). Here, the preposition after 'ask' is needed: (I asked for a flower for her / *I asked him  for a flower).

Comment: "I'm asking a flower for my mother" is not English, and I can only guess what it is intended to mean.

Comment: @ColinFine - What do you mean? I'm not English speaker and I realy want to know: Is it not a right way to say that?

Comment: Actually, I take that back. It is English, but it is a very unlikely thing to say, because it means that I am saying "Hello, flower, please give me my mother".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the form “I'm asking for *X*”, the meaning depends in part on what *X* is.

1.a. If *X* is an item or amount, the sentence typically is a statement that you are requesting that item or amount:

> I'm asking for bread ⇒ You want some bread
>   I'm asking for $100 ⇒ Your asking price is $100; or perhaps you want to cadge $100.

1.b. If *X* is *it*, as in “I'm asking for it”, you are saying your behavior has been such that someone is likely to take note and do something about it.

1.c. If *X* is a name or personal pronoun, the meaning is context dependent (or may be ambiguous).  “I'm asking for Janus” may mean (i) you are requesting Janus (ie, either asking to speak or meet with Janus, or asking that Janus be given up to you), or (ii) you are asking something on behalf of Janus rather than on your own behalf, or (iii) you are asking for something in place of Janus asking (nearly the same as ii).

---

> Do I have to say: I'm asking it/the flower for my mother

Regarding “I'm asking it for my mother”, see 1.c.(ii) or 1.c.(iii) above.  In this case, *it* might be a question or a request which you are asking or making because your mother cannot, or your mother asked you to do so, or you think it will benefit or serve your mother.

Regarding “I'm asking the flower for my mother”, this appears to say you are talking to the flower, requesting the flower to give you your mother.  Is that the request you meant to make??

---

> 2.What is the [difference] between “I'm asking a flower”  and  “I'm asking for a flower”?

The first of these says you are talking to a flower, asking it a question.  The other says you are requesting a flower, eg asking someone to give or sell you a flower.

---

I imagine that rather than “I'm asking a flower for my mother” you mean to say “I'm requesting a flower for my mother” or to say “I'm asking for a flower for my mother”.  As noted in other replies, *asking for* is more appropriate than just *asking* when you mean you are requesting something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm asking for a flower on behalf of my mother.

Comment: Is `on behalf of` in spoken English ?

Comment: @ParPar No reason why not.