# "Ask help/permission/forgiveness" or "Ask FOR help/permission/forgiveness"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I found some illustrative sentences as below in online-dictionaries ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ask) and [Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/ask)).

- If you need any help, please don't hesitate to ask.
- She asked their forgiveness.

Why they don't use "ask for" in this case?
What is the difference between "ask help/permission/forgiveness" and "ask for  help/permission/forgiveness"?

And please tell me how and when I can use "ask" instead of "ask for", as well.

Is usage of 'ask something' ('ask' with a direct object) limited **only** in the case of 'help/permission/forgiveness'?

Comment: It is idiomatic to drop the 'for' in the case of 'forgiveness' or 'permission', You can also 'ask a favour'. It is equally correct to 'ask for forgiveness/permission/etc.' But whilst you can 'ask Mr Greenway a question', if you want him to come to the phone, you have to 'ask for Mr Greenway'.

Comment: @WS2 Thank you. Is it equally correct **only** in the case of 'forgiveness' or 'permission'? So, you don't use 'ask' like ["I ask a flower for my mother."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194662/meaning-of-ask-for)?

Comment: Right, you don't "ask a flower for my mother".  Or any tangible thing. But you could "ask my mother for a flower!"

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock Thank you. I understand 'ask something intangible' is OK in some cases. Thanks.

Comment: This needs an extended answer. The complementation patterns of _help_ in particular are extremely complex. 'Ask a favour of X'; 'Ask a lot of X';  but *'Ask help of X'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you. "ask one's help" is OK?

Comment: I wouldn't use a bare 'We asked his help' myself, though I'd say this is 'dual usage' status rather than 'ungrammatical' or 'unacceptable'. I'd have far less of a problem with 'We asked their help in choosing ...' or 'We asked their help with the setting up of ...'. 'Padding' often makes borderline constructions sound more acceptable. 'We requested their help' / 'They sought his help' are fine. 'Ask' does behave transitively, perhaps as a result of pronoun deletion, but not with the freedom say 'request' does.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you very much. You made me clear. One dictionary named 'Kenkyusha's English-Japanese Dictionary' described "He asked our help." as a example and It made me confused. Thank you.

Comment: I'd not mark 'He asked our help' wrong, but it's much more usual to include 'for' in the UK, especially if there's not a with-phrase or equivalent. In the US, I'd say it wouldn't sound jarring at all. // 'You've made it clear for me', not 'You've made me clear', even though 'I'm clear about it now' is OK!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You've made it totally clear for me! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, *ask* has to do with *asking a question*, and *ask for* is equivalent to *request*.

Let's look a little more closely at the "help" sentence you found -- "If you need any help, please don't hesitate to ask."

I think there is a bit at the end that is implied but not expressed -- "If you need any help, please don't hesitate to ask (for some [help])."  I think the part in parentheses is generally left out because the idea is clear enough without it.

Here's another version of the same idea that would work in English: "If I'm in my office, you can always come in and ask for help if you need any.  Don't worry about interrupting me -- unless I'm on the phone, of course."

Now let's look at the "forgiveness" sentence.  Actually, as you were wondering, you could indeed also say, "She asked for their forgiveness."  But because of the repetition *for... for*, it sounds nicer the way your dictionary put it.

You asked about the difference between "ask help/permission/forgiveness" and "ask for help/permission/forgiveness."  You can say all six of those, except *ask help*.  That doesn't work.

*Ask permission* is more common than *ask for permission*, but this is the kind of thing you'll pick up naturally through practice.  If I imagine myself telling someone to ask permission first -- I'm probably talking to my ten-year-old, and I want to make an impact -- so I speak as concisely as I can, with no optional prepositions!

I hope this helps you feel more confidence.  I'm not a linguist -- but then, most English speakers aren't!

Answer (score 0):

As @WS2 suggested, a number of these expressions are idiomatic, resulting in the dropping of the (technically necessary) preposition. There isn't a pattern or rule, rather, as idioms, they're exempt from the rule.

Comment: Our linguistic version of the Great Wall of China, and perhaps just as effective.

Answer (score 0):

In many case, you would follow "forgiveness" with "for", such as "She asked their forgiveness for her forgetfulness." Adding "for" after "asked" in this scenario would be awkward. I suspect that the shortened version developed from this pattern.

Comment: Thank you for new interpretation. This is easy to remember.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it depends on the situation. "Ask for" is used more as advice (pushing you to do something), "ask" is more of an order (meaning you absolutely have to!).